# Threaded comments class gives me array error

Tags: php, mysql, oop

Fixed: In my database if the Parent is emty is 0 not NULL so i changed `if ($comment['Parent'] === NULL)` to `if ($comment['Parent'] < 1)` and it works now. I also change `$results = $ROW` to `$results[] = $ROW` if anyone wants to use this.

Thanks

I'm trying to implement a threaded comment class to my application. But I'm getting an error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'Parent' in Z:\Projects\icerik\html\test.php on line 25
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'Parent' in Z:\Projects\icerik\html\test.php on line 31

Database is CommensID - Comment - Parent - ContentID

here is the original code [code](http://www.jongales.com/blog/2009/01/27/php-class-for-threaded-comments/)

This is what `print_r($results);` displays

```
Array (
    [CommentsID] => 131
    [ContentID] => 1171
    [UserID] => 668
    [Comment] => hic birsey yapmamislar. bu programdan sonra spor haberleri sunmus. yalanincada olmus.
    [Time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [Parent] => 130
    [WriterIP] => 82.11.180.115
    [Active] => 1
    [TotalVotes] => 0
    [VoteSum] => 0
)
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php
//database connection

class Threaded_comments  
{  

    public $parents  = array();  
    public $children = array();  

    /** 
     * @param array $comments 
     */  
    function __construct($comments)  
    {  
        foreach ($comments as $comment)  
        {  
            if ($comment['Parent'] === NULL)  
            {  
                $this->parents[$comment['CommentsID']][] = $comment;  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                $this->children[$comment['Parent']][] = $comment;  
            }  
        }  
    }  

    /** 
     * @param array $comment 
     * @param int $depth 
     */  
    private function format_comment($comment, $depth)  
    {  
        for ($depth; $depth > 0; $depth--)  
        {  
            echo "--";  
        }  

        echo $comment['Comment'];  
        echo "<br />";  
    }  

    /** 
     * @param array $comment 
     * @param int $depth 
     */  
    private function print_parent($comment, $depth = 0)  
    {  
        foreach ($comment as $c)  
        {  
            $this->format_comment($c, $depth);  

            if (isset($this->children[$c['CommentsID']]))  
            {  
                $this->print_parent($this->children[$c['CommentsID']], $depth + 1);  
            }  
        }  
    }  

    public function print_comments()  
    {  
        foreach ($this->parents as $c)  
        {  
            $this->print_parent($c);  
        }  
    }  

}

$sql = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE ContentID = 1171");
$sql->execute();

$results = array();

while($ROW = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $results = $ROW;
} 

$threaded_comments = new Threaded_comments($results);  

$threaded_comments->print_comments(); 
?>
```

Comment: use `isset($comment['Parent'])` to test if array contains `Parent` index. Not: `$comment['Parent']===null`

Comment: it is exsit and if you see my question when you print_r the results it shows that Parent has an ID

Comment: Change `$results = $ROW;` to `$results[] = $ROW;`

Comment: it won't display anything. the print out like this: 'array(array('CommentsID' => '2321', 'Comment' => 'text', 'Parent' => '1235'))'

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code.I think that should work for you.

```
$results = array();
while($ROW = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
   $results[] = $ROW;
}
```

Change `$results = $ROW;` to `$results[] = $ROW;`

Warning is showing because :

```
foreach ($comments as $comment)  
{
  // Here **$comment** should not be an array according to your code
  // Your code goes here  
}
```

So you can do like this :

```
foreach ($comments as $key => $value)  
    {
      if($key == 'Parent') {
         $this->parents[$comments[$key]][] = $comments;
      } else {

      }
      // Your code goes here  
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I've tried that. It does not print anything becouse it adds one more array into it. the print out like this: {array(array('CommentsID' => '2321', 'Comment' => 'text', 'Parent' => '1235'))}

Comment: @ErdemEce So what is the problem if you use multidimensional array.